Como obtener solo un registro de que se repite 4 veces en una consulta en SQL SERVER?
Estoy teniendo problemas al intentar obtener unos datos de un join entre dos tablas, la cuestión es que se repite un dato y quiero que no se repita, por cuestión de privacidad les puedo poner un ejemplo:
Digamos tengo la siguiente consulta
Select b.id_empleado,b.NombreEmpleado,a.Usuario from Usuarios a inner join empleados b on a.correlativoempleado=b.correlativoempleado

Me trae los siguientes datos:

Entonces en el caso de "Jose Castillo" quiero que solo aparezca una vez y los demás obviamente sigan apareciendo, ya he probado con group by y no me ha funcionado, y lo único que se me ocurre es una chambonada de hacer un union all.
Es decir hago un select donde no lleve a ese usuario y unido con otro select donde haga un top 1 y solo lleve ese usuario.
Pero no se que otras opciones tengo, ¿me podrían ayudar?
Básicamente hasta el momento ya agoté usar distinct y usar group by, si conocen otro método o si tienen algun link de referencia se los agradecería.
De antemano gracias

Una nota marginal: aliases deben hacer mas legible la consulta. Aliases arbitrarios hacen lo contrario. En vez, usa aliases apropriados, como u para usarios y e para empleados.

Usa el operador distinct, que realiza justo lo que quieres, pues elimina del resultado todas las filas que están duplicadas, por lo que cada fila aparece una sola vez.
así:
select distinct b.id_empleado,b.NombreEmpleado,a.Usuario 
  from Usuarios a 
       inner join empleados b on a.correlativoempleado = b.correlativoempleado


lo que pasa es que igual como enrealidad son mas campos, eso no me funciona, ya lo he intentado asi

@Javier, entonces coloca un ejemplo que denote tu verdadero problema. Con el ejemplo que pusiste, esta respuesta es válida. Te recomiendo leer [mcve] y [ask].

Javier Ramirez: Te recomendo aceptar esta respuesta porque contesta tu pregunta correctamente. Obviamente tienes otra problema (probablemente quieres agregar y agrupar tus datos), lo que puedes explicar en nueva pregunta.
